# Discord.js Embed error Cannot send an empty message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so I'm trying to make a help command with list of commands showed in embed. My code kinda works but it throws an error "DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message" and I've tried already everything I know and what I've found but I can't fix it.

Here's the code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix } = require('../config.json');

module.exports = {
  name: 'help',
  description: 'List all of my commands or info about a specific command.',
  aliases: ['commands', 'cmds'],
  usage: '[command name]',
  cooldown: 5,
  execute(msg, args) {

    const data = [];
    const { commands } = msg.client;

    if (!args.length) {

        const helpEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('YELLOW')
            .setTitle('Here\'s a list of all my commands:')
            .setDescription(commands.map(cmd => cmd.name).join('\n'))
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(`You can send \`${prefix}help [command name]\` to get info on a specific command!`);

        msg.author.send(helpEmbed);

        return msg.author.send(data, { split: true })
            .then(() => {
                if (msg.channel.type === 'dm') return;
                msg.reply('I\'ve sent you a DM with all my commands!');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(`Could not send help DM to ${msg.author.tag}.\n`, error);
                msg.reply('it seems like I can\'t DM you! Do you have DMs disabled?');
            });
    }

    const name = args[0].toLowerCase();
    const command = commands.get(name) || commands.find(c => c.aliases && c.aliases.includes(name));

    if (!command) {
        return msg.reply('that\'s not a valid command!');
    }

    data.push(`**Name:** ${command.name}`);

    if (command.aliases) data.push(`**Aliases:** ${command.aliases.join(', ')}`);
    if (command.description) data.push(`**Description:** ${command.description}`);
    if (command.usage) data.push(`**Usage:** ${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}`);

    data.push(`**Cooldown:** ${command.cooldown || 3} second(s)`);

    msg.channel.send(data, { split: true });
 },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try replace this line :
`msg.channel.send(data, { split: true });`

with
`msg.channel.send(data.join(' '), { split: true });` since your data variable is an array and not a string

Comment: Sadly same result

Comment: @Soulhax @Soulhax you've made the same mistake on this line : `return msg.author.send(data, { split: true })
`

Comment: I tried replacing both but it's still the same. Replacing both makes it even a bit worse tho. 

When both replaced: https://imgur.com/a/QJZbGsy

When it's the original code: https://imgur.com/a/8MaVYJD

Comment: @Soulhax what do you mean worse ?

Comment: added links to pictures so you can see

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as the error states. You are trying to send an empty message somewhere.

You can try replacing `msg.channel.send(data)` with `msg.channel.send(data.join('\n'))`, since the `data` variable is an array.

I don't see why sending an array doesn't work though.

Comment: Sending arrays does not work because discord.js does not allow it I suppose

Comment: Sadly still the same result

Comment: I think your problem is not that you're trying to send an array, but that the array is empty. What if you tried doing `var data` rather than `const data`?

Comment: @ComputerGeek12 yeah the problem is cons dat = [] but I can't replace it with var. If I just set it to something then the command works without error.